# Using list item contents as string name

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection

I'm using C# and making lists from sqlite query responses.

List1 contains a field with the name of a field in list2

```
List1[i].field = fieldname
```

I want to use the fieldname stored in `List1[i].field` to access an item in `List2` something like:

```
List2[ii].+List1[i].field+
```

I have no idea if this is possible in this way in C# i'm relatively new to it and essentially going off my knowledge of PHP where something like this does work.

Comment: can you please explain yourself a little bit more.. I can think of 2 or 3 different things that you're trying to do.. but without a more meaningful example it's hard to determine what you are asking.

Comment: I am trying to use the value stored in a list to access a value stored in another list. Under the name stored in list2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this type of data structure, you usually use a dictionary (key/value pairs) to dynamically select properties of an object. For your specific example, this could be accomplished with reflection, but it is not very commonly used since other structures make it much easier.

```
List2[ii].GetType().GetProperty(List1[i].field).GetValue(List2[ii], null);
```

Reflection isn't the fastest type of solution typically, and it's usually not great to come in behind and maintain code with a lot of reflection if it can be avoided.

Alternatively, you could use Linq to transfer List2 from a list of your object types into a list of dictionary objects so you could do something like `List2[ii][List1[i].field]` to accomplish the same thing.

```
var listDictionaries = List2
    .Select(l => new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        new { "Prop1", l.Prop1 },
        new { "Prop2", l.Prop2 },
        new { "Prop3", l.Prop3 },
    }).ToArray();
listDictionaries[ii][List1[i].field];
```

Comment: Happy to help. I put in some additional info about the Dictionary I mentioned in case it would help you. It's a lot easier to work with than reflection.

Comment: Thanks, Ill have a think about changing my approach.